Indesign grep: Keep the two first words of a sentence together
How can I make sure that the two first words of any sentence are together on the same line. For example below, I want to have "To" and "make " automatically on the same line. I am sure there is a Grep script than could solve it.


For a single instance, one can select both words and from the Character Panel flyout menu choose no break.

Yes, but I wanted to automatize for a long document.
